# OpenGL context from glut

Tags: opengl, opencl, glut

Question: Is there anyway at all to get an OpenGL context from GLUT?

---

Info: I've been working on learning openGL and openCL. I'm almost done with my first program that makes use of them together, everything would work wonderfully if I could only create create my openCL context, but to do that and get the sharing working I need to get an openGL context. I could go through the process of dealing with X, but I was hoping to keep this as platform-independent as possible with the fewest possible libraries. I'll just have to figure out something else if there is isn't. but I figured I should at least ask before I give up. Is there anyway, anyway at all, to get an OpenGL context from GLUT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the context from GLUT, but you can get it from *Windows*: `wglGetCurrentContext`. Similarly, on X-Windows systems, you may use `glXGetCurrentContext`.

Comment: @Narcolapser: Why is that something to be "afraid of"? The context types are different for the different APIs anyway, so whatever any GLUT function returned would have to be `#define`d or otherwise `#ifdef`d around.

Comment: right. and i was afraid of that because this means I have to rework parts of my program that I thought I was done with. its just a hassle is all. More time. I was hoping to be done with this yesterday. oh well, life goes on.